# Why does tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() truncate my data?

Tags: python

Here is a test I created to recreate a problem I was having when I used
tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(). The problem is that when I use tempfile the
data in my CSV is truncated off the end of the file.

When you run this test script, temp2.csv will get truncated and temp1.csv
will be the same size as the original CSV.

I'm using Python 2.7.1.

You can download the sample CSV from http://explore.data.gov/Energy-and-Utilities/Residential-Energy-Consumption-Survey-RECS-Files-A/eypy-jxs2

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import tempfile
import shutil


def main():
    f = open('RECS05alldata.csv')
    data = f.read()
    f.close()

    f = open('temp1.csv', 'w+b')
    f.write(data)
    f.close()

    temp = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
    temp.write(data)
    shutil.copy(temp.name, 'temp2.csv')
    temp.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add temp.flush() after temp.write(data).

Comment: That worked, but seems a little counterintuitive. It seems like temp.flush() should go before temp.write(data) in my mind. Which is something I tried before and it didn't work. I wish I understood better why it works to put it after write().

Answer (score 3):

You copy the file before you close it. Files are buffered, which means that some of it will remain in the buffer while it is waiting to be written to the file. The `close` will write out all remaining data from the buffer to the file as part of the closing of the file.

This has nothing to do with `NamedTemporaryFile`.

Comment: Or [flush()](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file.flush) in cases where you don't want the file to be closed yet, but do want data written out.

Comment: @BrendanLong, you generally don't want to copy a file until you're done with it - but your point is valid.

Comment: Python 2.6+ has a `delete=True` parameter for this method, "If delete is true (the default), the file is deleted as soon as it is closed"
That could be confusing if you assume that this behaves the same way as the `open()` method and instinctively `close()` the `NamedTemporaryFile` before copying it, because it will be gone, and the copy will error.  `flush()` is the  solution here.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that Python has not flushed the entire file to disk when you call `shutil.copy`.

Change

```
temp = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
temp.write(data)
shutil.copy(temp.name, 'temp2.csv')
temp.close()
```

to

```
temp = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
temp.write(data)
temp.close()
shutil.copy(temp.name, 'temp2.csv')
```

Comment: This won't work on Python2.6+ , see the `delete` parameter https://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile